# Компилятор не видит функцию в многофайловом проекте СИ

Tags: c

Содержание файла main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"


int main(){
    long number;
    printf("Input the long type argument: \n\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &number) == 1){
        printf("Result: %s", ltoab(number));
    }
    else{
        printf("Incorrect input!");
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Содержание файла functions.h:

`char* ltoab(long num);`

Содержание файла functions.c:

```
#include "functions.h"

char *ltoab(long num)
{
    static char binNum[sizeof(num) * 8];
    int i = sizeof(num) * 8;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        if ((num & 1) == 0)
        {
            binNum[i] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            binNum[i] = '1';
        }
        i--;
        num >>= 1;
    }
    binNum[sizeof(num)*8] = '\0';
    return binNum;
}
```

При запуске файла main.c возникает ошибка `undefined reference to ltoab`.
Вопрос состоит в том что не так и как это исправить ?

Comment: Компилировать оба файла. И `main.c` и `functions.c`

Comment: как это можно сделать ? Просто при запуске файла functions.c возникает ошибка undefined reference to `WinMain@16' . Предполагаю что это значит, что в файле нет главной функции main()

Comment: @asdqwedfsdf, а как вы запускаете компилятор?

Comment: через VSCode запускаю

Comment: Значит в `tasks.json` нужно указать файлы.